# how to disable logging in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I want disable logging in clickhouse. I tried disable sections query_log and query_thread_log in `config.xml`, but it didn't help me. I tried run sql query:

```
ALTER TABLE system.settings

UPDATE log_queries = 0 WHERE name = 'log_queries'
```

But I get the error:

> Code: 48. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception:
> Table engine SystemSettings doesn't support mutations.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check these

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-server-config-files

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-system-tables-eat-my-disk

system.settings -- is a virtual table you cannot change it directly. It reflects states of a session settings (they are c++ structures in a session memory).

- You can change setting for a session `set log_queries = 0;`
- Or you can change user's profile:

```
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/log_queries.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
  <users>
    <default>
      <log_queries>0</log_queries>
    </default>
  </users>
</yandex>
```