# Disable clickhouse logs in the system database

Tags: database, clickhouse

In clickhouse, there is a database called system where logs are stored.

My problem is that after installing clickhouse, the volume of the system database has increased a day, and I sent a photo of it, and if I only use it for 30 days, I have to allocate nearly 30 gigs of space on the server just for the system database, which costs It will be high.
Especially the two tables `trace_log` and `part_log` take a lot of space

[image]

How to disable the logs in the system database?

I have already seen the link below and did everything and it didn't work ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68455527/8519380)).
The following command does not work to prevent system database logs:

```
set log_queries = 0;
```

And also the following code does not work for me:

```
cat /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/log_queries.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<yandex>
  <users>
    <default>
      <log_queries>0</log_queries>
    </default>
  </users>
</yandex>
```

I even went to this path `sudo nano /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml`
and I entered the following values, but it didn't work:

```
<logger>
    <level>none</level>
    <output>null</output>
</logger>
```

In addition, I restarted clickhouse every time to apply the changes
It is interesting here that when I do not insert any data into my database in my codes, the system database increases in size for no reason.
I searched a lot and did a lot of tests, but I didn't get any results. Thank you for your guidance

Comment: log_queries is not related to trace_log. Read your links  (I wrote those articles in the altinity KB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-system-tables-eat-my-disk/

You can disable all / any of them

Do not create log tables at all (a restart is needed for these changes to take effect).

```
$ cat /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/z_log_disable.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<clickhouse>
    <asynchronous_metric_log remove="1"/>
    <metric_log remove="1"/>
    <query_thread_log remove="1" />  
    <query_log remove="1" />
    <query_views_log remove="1" />
    <part_log remove="1"/>
    <session_log remove="1"/>
    <text_log remove="1" />
    <trace_log remove="1"/>
    <crash_log remove="1"/>
    <opentelemetry_span_log remove="1"/>
    <zookeeper_log remove="1"/>
</clickhouse>
```

And you need to drop existing tables

```sql
drop table system.trace_log;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The settings you referenced control the `query_log` table, more details are available here:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/query_log/

Note that it is not recommended to turn off the `query_log` because information in this table is important for solving issues.

The `trace_log` and `part_log` tables are different and shouldn't be enabled by default, you can locate these blocks in your config.xml and comment them:

```
<trace_log>
    <database>system</database>
    <table>trace_log</table>
    <partition_by>toYYYYMM(event_date)</partition_by>
    <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
</trace_log>
```

and

```
<part_log>
    <database>system</database>
    <table>part_log</table>
    <partition_by>toMonday(event_date)</partition_by>
    <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
</part_log>
```

Reference:

- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#server_configuration_parameters-trace_log
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings/#server_configuration_parameters-part-log